# Fitting a very wide longtable into the page width

Tags: latex, pdflatex

I would like to create a longtable for my appendix listing all of the experiments I have performed throughout my study. However it is very wide and I would like to fit it into my page width.

```
\usepackage{longtable}

\centering
\begin{longtable}{ccccccccccc}
    Date                                     & Encoding & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Model\\Architecture\end{tabular}                                                                                                                           & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}LSTM\\Units\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Batch\\Size\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Embedding\\Vector\\Length\end{tabular} & Optimizer                   & Ratio & Epochs & Accuracy  \\
    15/02/2018                               & Integer  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}1 LSTM Layer\\w/ 0.5 surrounding Dropout\end{tabular}                                                                                                      & 100                                                 & 64                                                  & 32                                                                & RMSprop                     & 80/20 & 300    & 86.87     \\
    17/02/2018                               & Integer  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}1 LSTM Layer\\w/ 0.29 LSTM dropout\\w/ 0.33 LSTM recurrent dropout\end{tabular}                                                                            & 100                                                 & 64                                                  & 32                                                                & RMSprop                     & 80/20 & 300    & 83.43     \\
    18/02/2018                               & Integer  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}{1 LSTM Layer}\\w/ 0.5 surrounding Dropout\\w/ 0.2 LSTM dropout\\w/ 0.2 LSTM recurrent dropout\end{tabular}                    & 100                                                 & 64                                                  & 32                                                                & RMSprop                     & 80/20 & 500    & 87.34     \\
    18/02/2018 & Integer  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}{1 LSTM Layer}\\w/ 0.5 surrounding Dropout\\w/ 0.3 LSTM dropout\\w/ 0.3 LSTM recurrent dropout\end{tabular}                    & 100                                                 & 64                                                  & 32                                                                & RMSprop                     & 80/20 & 500    & 87.6      \\
    17/02/2018                               & Integer  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}{1 LSTM Layer}\\w/ 0.5 surrounding Dropout\\w/ 0.1 LSTM dropout\\w/ 0.1 LSTM recurrent dropout\end{tabular}                    & 100                                                 & 64                                                  & 32                                                                & RMSprop                     & 80/20 & 500    & 87.7      \\
    18/02/2018 & Integer  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}{1 LSTM Layer}\\w/ 0.5 surrounding Dropout\\w/ 0.25 LSTM dropout\\w/ 0.25 LSTM recurrent dropout\end{tabular}                  & 100                                                 & 64                                                  & 32                                                                & RMSprop                     & 80/20 & 500    & 87.91     \\
    16/02/2018                               & Integer  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}1 LSTM Layer\\w/ 0.3 LSTM dropout\\w/ 0.3 LSTM recurrent dropout\end{tabular}                                                                              & 100                                                 & 64                                                  & 32                                                                & \multicolumn{1}{l}{RMSprop} & 80/20 & 500    & 86.57     \\
    21/02/2018                               & Integer  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}{1 LSTM Layer}\\w/ 0.5 surrounding Dropout\\w/ 0.5 LSTM dropout\\w/ 0.5 LSTM recurrent dropout\end{tabular}                    & 100                                                 & 64                                                  & 64                                                                & adam                        & 80/20 & 700    & 87.67     \\
    19/02/2018                               & Integer  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}{1 LSTM Layer}\\w/ 0.5 surrounding Dropout\\w/ 0.225 LSTM dropout\\w/ 0.225 LSTM recurrent dropout\end{tabular}                & 100                                                 & 64                                                  & 32                                                                & RMSprop                     & 80/20 & 700    & 86.97     \\
    19/02/2018                               & Integer  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}{1 LSTM Layer}\\w/ 0.5 surrounding Dropout\\w/ 0.275 LSTM dropout\\w/ 0.275 LSTM recurrent dropout\end{tabular}                & 100                                                 & 64                                                  & 32                                                                & RMSprop                     & 80/20 & 700    & 86.5      \\
    21/02/2018                               & Integer  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}{1 LSTM Layer}\\w/ 0.5 surrounding Dropout\\w/ 0.25 LSTM dropout\\w/ 0.25 LSTM recurrent dropout\end{tabular}                  & 100                                                 & 64                                                  & 64                                                                & RMSprop                     & 80/20 & 700    & 88.21     \\
    20/02/2018                               & Integer  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}{1 LSTM Layer}\\w/ 0.5 surrounding Dropout\\w/ 0.25 LSTM dropout\\w/ 0.1 LSTM recurrent dropout\end{tabular}                   & 100                                                 & 64                                                  & 32                                                                & RMSprop                     & 80/20 & 700    & 87.94     \\
    21/02/2018                               & Integer  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}{1 LSTM Layer}\\w/ 0.4 surrounding Dropout\\w/ 0.25 LSTM dropout\\w/ 0.25 LSTM recurrent dropout\end{tabular}                  & 100                                                 & 64                                                  & 32                                                                & RMSprop                     & 80/20 & 1000   & 87.44     \\
    20/02/2018                               & Integer  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}{1 LSTM Layer}\\w/ 0.5 surrounding Dropout\\w/ 0.24 LSTM dropout\\w/ 0.24 LSTM recurrent dropout\end{tabular}                  & 100                                                 & 64                                                  & 32                                                                & RMSprop                     & 80/20 & 1000   & 88.07     \\
    25/02/2018                               & Integer  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}{1 LSTM Layer}\\w/ 0.5 surrounding Dropout\\w/ 0.255 LSTM dropout\\w/ 0.255 LSTM recurrent dropout\end{tabular}                & 200                                                 & 64                                                  & 64                                                                & RMSprop                     & 90/10 & 300    & 88.77     \\
    25/02/2018                               & Integer  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}{1 LSTM Layer}\\w/ 0.5 surrounding Dropout\\w/ 0.26 LSTM dropout\\w/ 0.26 LSTM recurrent dropout\end{tabular}                  & 100                                                 & 64                                                  & 64                                                                & RMSprop                     & 90/10 & 600    & 89.64     \\
    22/02/2018                               & Integer  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}{1 LSTM Layer}\\w/ 0.5 surrounding Dropout\\w/ 0.25 LSTM dropout\\w/ 0.25 LSTM recurrent dropout\end{tabular}                  & 100                                                 & 64                                                  & 64                                                                & RMSprop                     & 90/10 & 800    & 88.37     \\
    25/02/2018                               & Integer  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}{1 LSTM Layer}\\w/ 0.5 surrounding Dropout\\w/ 0.265 LSTM dropout\\w/ 0.265 LSTM recurrent dropout\end{tabular}                & 100                                                 & 64                                                  & 64                                                                & RMSprop                     & 90/10 & 1000   & 89.71     \\
    01/03/2018                               & Integer  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}{1 LSTM Layer}\\w/ 0.5 surrounding Dropout\\w/ 0.26 LSTM dropout\\w/ 0.26 LSTM recurrent dropout\\w/ Class Weight\end{tabular} & 100                                                 & 64                                                  & 64                                                                & RMSprop                     & 90/10 & 1000   & 89.91     \\
    22/02/2018                               & Integer  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}{1 LSTM Layer}\\w/ 0.5 surrounding Dropout\\w/ 0.25 LSTM dropout\\w/ 0.25 LSTM recurrent dropout\end{tabular}                  & 200                                                 & 64                                                  & 64                                                                & RMSprop                     & 80/20 & 800    & 87.77     \\
    23/02/2018                               & Integer  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}1 LSTM Layer\\w/ 0.3 LSTM dropout\\w/ 0.3 LSTM recurrent dropout\end{tabular}                                                                              & 200                                                 & 64                                                  & 64                                                                & RMSprop                     & 80/20 & 400    & 87.47     \\
    23/02/2018                               & Integer  & 1 LSTM Layer                                                                                                                                                                          & 200                                                 & 64                                                  & 64                                                                & RMSprop                     & 80/20 & 200    & 87.4        
\end{longtable}
```

This produces:

[image: out of page longtable]

Comment: [Fit a very wide table on the page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/308637/fit-a-very-wide-table-on-the-page)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to specify the size of the columns and find the best balance you need, as in the following command:

```tex
    \begin{longtable}{|p{1cm}|p{3cm}|...|p{3cm}|}
```

Comment: please take care of proper formatting before you post your answer. You meant to use {} not <>